# Tryparse isn't using the else statement when invalid input is entered

Tags: c#, tryparse

The else statement, "Weight must be greater than 0" is working, but if I were to enter a letter into my `PackageWeight.Text` textbox, the else statement won't show.

```
if (decimal.TryParse(PackageWeight.Text, out weight))
{
    if (weight > 0)
    {
        weightcost = pound * weight;
        Weight.Text = weightcost.ToString("c");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Weight must be greater than 0.");
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid input for weight.");
}
```

Comment: It probably is about C# not C isn't it?

Comment: I fixed the tag, thank you

Comment: So neither the statement associated with the outer `else` nor the inner `else` show?

Comment: The inner else will show, but now the outer else.

Comment: What are you test inputs? What is failing to fire the outer else-statement?

Comment: Did you mean, when you enter into the PackageWeight.Text, rather than the Weight.Text?   Weight.Text is where your output is going

Comment: The code looks fine. Make sure you are not running old version of the executable.

Comment: Sorry, yes I did mean the PackageWeight.Text. For example if I were to type the letter "b" into the textbox and click calculate, it doesn't show my messagebox from the else statement, instead it throws an exception.

Comment: What is the exception and from where does it throw it?  Have you stepped through in Debug?

Comment: @Brad Just for future reference, when you ask a question if you include any exceptions and input/output information it would help everyone.

Comment: Just tested your code and it's working fine. Are you using a button click event to trigger the code?

Comment: Thank you for the advice Shelby, I'm new to the forums, but I went through the debugger and figured it out. Thank you also Dijkgraaf for opening my eyes lol.

Comment: When I initially assigned the weight variable, i had "decimal weight = decimal.Parse(PackageWeight.Text);" and that was the problem.

Comment: If you put an **edit** in your question explaining that you found your coding error, it will help people who would otherwise have to read through all the comments to figure out that you solved it, and their problem is probably not the same as yours.

Comment: Sorry about that @Craig.Feied I changed the title.

Comment: @Craig.Feied that is against our policy. A question shouldn't be edited to reflect an answer. @ Brad If you found an answer then you can post an answer to your question and mark it as accepted. That is how you let other ppl know you found a solution. If you feel the problem was trivial or simple a typo and the answer wouldn't help anyone else, then you can delete your own question. I have rolled back the edit that adds information about the solve status.

Comment: @bolov policy or not, the question now does not make much sense, because the problem for which the OP was seeking a solution *is not in the posted code*.  But I agree that writing his own answer and accepting it would be almost as good. Deletion probably is not as good a solution now that tymtam has posted working code with output.

Comment: @Craig.Feied  In that case the question should be closed as off-topic (for which it already has two votes).

Answer (score 0):

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Parse("1");
            Parse("-1");
            Parse("DDD");
        }

        private static void Parse(string x)
        {
            if (decimal.TryParse(x, out decimal weight))
            {
                if (weight > 0)
                {
                    var weightcost = 2 * weight;
                    Console.WriteLine(weightcost.ToString("c"));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Weight must be greater than 0.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input for weight.");
            }
        }
```

produces the correct output:

[image]